# why migration is required during editing enum in prisma schema

Tags: node.js, prisma, prisma2

```
enum OrderStatus {
    paymentDone
    OrderCreated
    OrderConfirmed
}
```

iam using prima postgres db
if you add an extra literal `orderCancelled` in prisma schema it is asking for creating a new migration , why it behaves like this ?

Comment: Which database are you using? Are the enums stored in the database which you are using?

Comment: iam using prisma in postgres sql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the expected behaviour.
Initially when the enum had 3 values, this migration script would have been executed.

```sql
CREATE TYPE "OrderStatus" AS ENUM ('paymentDone', 'OrderCreated', 'OrderConfirmed');
```

When you are adding a new enum `OrderCancelled`, the `OrderStatus` type needs to be altered like this.

```sql
ALTER TYPE "OrderStatus" ADD VALUE 'OrderCancelled';
```

So Prisma Migrate initiating a new migration is the correct behavior.